# Yii transactions and validations issue

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm doing a webapp where the user can choose their holiday periods. Since he doesn't need to select all the weeks at once I'm fusioning consecutive holiday periods in the
save() method of the HolidayPeriod model (within a transaction).

My problem is that one of the validation in the rules() of HolidayPeriod is that the new period doesn't overlap with any existing period. So my actual code is:

```
public function save($runValidation = true, $attributes = null)
{
    $ts = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
       $periods=$this->user->holidayPeriods;
       foreach ($periods as $period){
            if ($this->isConsecutiveWith($period)){
                $this->fusion($period);
            } 
       }
       if ($result = parent::save($runValidation, $attributes)) {

         ....................
         ....................


private function fusion($period){
    $this->start=date('Y-m-d',min(strtotime($this->start),strtotime($period->start)));
    $this->end=date('Y-m-d',max(strtotime($this->end),strtotime($period->end)));
    if (!$period->delete()){
        echo "FAIL<BR>";
        throw new Exception();
    }else {
        echo "OK<BR>";          
    }   
}
```

The problem there is that when calling **parent::save($runValidation, $attributes)** the validation detects the deleted periods as overlapped and it fails. So I made a simple test:

```
 $periods=$this->user->holidayPeriods;
 echo count($periods);
 foreach($periods as $period){
     $period->delete();
 }
 echo count($this->user->holidayPeriods);
```

And both calls to **echo** print the same number at the start and at the end.

How can I make the $this->user->holidayPeriods to be updated after the delete()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the $this->user->holidayPeriods to be updated after the delete()?

(Assuming this is a relation defined in `relations()`) You can:

- `unset($this->user->holidayPeriods)` - the next time you access `$this->user->holidayPeriods`, it will be loaded from the DB.
- `$this->user->getRelated('holidayPeriods', true)` - forces the `holidayPeriods` relation to be refreshed from the DB right there.
- Avoid the refresh from DB entirely:

  ```
  $periods = $this->user->holidayPeriods;
  foreach ($periods as $ix => $period){
    if ($this->isConsecutiveWith($period)){
      $this->fusion($period);
      unset($periods[$ix]);
    }
  }
  $periods = array_values($periods); // fix period indexes
  unset($this->user->holidayPeriods);
  $this->user->addRelatedRecord('holidayPeriods', $periods, false);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You're not deleting anything from "$this->user->holidayPeriods". By doing this: `$periods=$this->user->holidayPeriods;` you're only passing the value of `$this->user->holidayPeriods` to the variable "$periods". So, when you modify "$periods" you're not doing anything to `$this->user->holidayPeriods`. So try something like this:

```
 foreach($this->user->holidayPeriods as $period){
    if ($this->isConsecutiveWith($period)){
       $this->fusion($period);
     } 
 }
```